# In Flash, how would I run an e4x statement when that statement is stored in a String?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

So I have something like this:

```
var xmlStatement:String = "xmlObject.node[3].@thisValue";
```

What mystery function do I have to use so that I can execute xmlStatement and get thisValue from that xmlObject? Like....

```
var attribute:String = mysteryFunction(xmlStatement);
```

P.S. I know eval() works for actionscript2, I need the as3 solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in ActionScript 3. This however might be a solution: http://blog.betabong.com/2008/09/23/e4x-string-parser/

Answer (score 0):

For your example it would be:
var attribute : String = String( E4X.evaluate( XMLList(xmlobject) , 'node[3].@thisValue' ) );